# SQL Server - Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted error

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run this Sql query I get this error.

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression."

I am using IN in my where condition, so I am not sure what the problem is when it returns more than 1 values from the sub query.

> If I remove the CASE statement and just run with

```
WHERE MCO_ID IN(SELECT  MCO_ID FROM @ALL_MCO)
```

then it works fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
DECLARE @MCO INT 
SET @MCO ='99'  -- This will be dynamic variable. I am just setting here for example 

DECLARE @ALL_MCO TABLE
(
    MCO_VALUE INT
)
INSERT INTO @ALL_MCO VALUES ('1')
INSERT INTO @ALL_MCO VALUES ('2')
INSERT INTO @ALL_MCO VALUES ('3')

SELECT *
FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE MCO_ID IN ( 
                 CASE WHEN  @MCO  ='99' THEN 
                      (SELECT  MCO_VALUE FROM @ALL_MCO)
                   ELSE 
                       @MCO END
                )
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the subquery 'SELECT  MCO_ID FROM @ALL_MCO'?   it does not make sense for it to return multiple values in this context, thus the error.

Comment: @jp2g With 'SELECT MCO_ID FROM ALL_MCO' I am trying to get all 3 MCO_VALUE that I inserted in the table variable. I need that, because I will be passing multiple values in MCO variable. If I pass '99' I need to query all the MCO values. In some situation I will just get a specific value in MCO other than 99, so that time I want to query for that specific MCO_VALUE with else condition.     
About the error. I am using IN operator so it should accept more than 1 values in WHERE condition.

Comment: I had made an error while posting and gave the same name for table variable and where condition 'MCO_ID. I have changed the table variable to MCO_VALUE. (This is not an error in actual query, it was just typo here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL `CASE` is an expression that returns a single scalar value. It cannot be used like in procedural languages to control execution flow.

You can try rewritting your `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
WHERE 
   (@MCO = '99' AND MCO_ID IN (SELECT MCO_ID FROM @ALL_MCO))
   OR
   (@MCO != '99' AND MCO_ID = @MCO)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works for me and now I understand the error message regarding the .....when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 1):

Your *where* clause doesn't make sense (at least for me) but you could use `exists` instead

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST_TABLE t
WHERE (@MCO = 99 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @ALL_MCO WHERE MCO_ID = t.MCO_ID)) OR
      (@MCO <> 99 AND MCO_ID = @MCO);
```

However, `@MCO` variable has `INT` type so, you don't need to use single quote

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST_TABLE
--WHERE MCO_ID IN( CASE WHEN  @MCO  ='99' THEN (SELECT  MCO_ID FROM @ALL_MCO) ELSE @MCO END)
WHERE (@MCO  ='99' AND MCO_ID IN (SELECT  MCO_ID FROM @ALL_MCO))
    OR (@MCO  !='99' AND MCO_ID = @MCO)
```

Comment: Thank you. Got the concept from your answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you meant to do?

```
DECLARE @MCO INT 
SET @MCO ='99'

DECLARE @ALL_MCO TABLE
(
    MCO_ID INT
)
INSERT INTO @ALL_MCO VALUES ('1')
INSERT INTO @ALL_MCO VALUES ('2')
INSERT INTO @ALL_MCO VALUES ('3')

SELECT *
FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE (@MCO = '99' AND MCO_ID IN (SELECT MCO_ID FROM @ALL_MCO))
   OR (@MCO <> '99' AND MCO_ID = @MCO)
```

Comment: Thank you. Got the concept from your answer as well.